# connect to a specific user on a server with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, remotewebdriver

I'm user Selenium remote web driver to run Selenium. The selenium code is in Java, running on Lynux. The server is on a Windows server machine, that has multiple users. The problem is that the selenium server is one per machine, so it doesn't matter how many users log on to it, Selenium will always open at the environment of the user that opened the server. This makes sense, as I use the machine ip to connect to Selenium, and it doesn't matter how many users the machine has, it would always have the same ip. So, I wanted to know if there is a way to tell Selenium to connect to a specific user on a machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you connect into a remote machine by SSH as I expect you do you relate that connection with the user that open the socket. so if you connect by ssh as 'Foo' you should do it as:

```
            'ssh -i ./ssh_key foo@selenium_ip'
```

so for that machine foo is connected.

Comment: The connection here is done via remote webdriver: mDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(url,cap ). Adding my username before the ip just causes a crash

Comment: what is the mechanism that you use to authenticate with that server?

Comment: none. I have Selenium standalone server  running on Windows side, and Selenium knows to connect to it

Comment: In every connection always musty be a user, figure out where is specify, because that is the user that selenium in Windows is using.